# WebtextEdit execute Javascript function

Tags: javascript

I need to execute an entire javascript function.

Found what I was doing wrong:

```
var edit = igedit_getById("FG2100RefNo");
var editText = edit.getText();
alert(!isNaN(editText));
```

But, this only checks & displays a message box.

I need to execute the below javascript:

```
<script language=Javascript>
  <!--
  function isNumberKey(evt)
  {
     var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
     if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        return false;

     return true;
  }
  //-->
```

```
onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"
```

**How can I do this with the webtextedit:**

```
var edit = igedit_getById("FG2100RefNo");
var editText = edit.getText();
function isNumberKey(evt)
{
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) return false;
    return true;
}
return isNumberKey(editText)
```

I only have the `onkey` event property value to insert the code.

Answer (score 0):

Your `onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"` function is sufficient to force user type only numerics.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide the client function name to the control's `ClientSideEvents.KeyPress` property from the server-side.

C#:

```
FG2100RefNo.ClientSideEvents.KeyPress = "isNumberKey";
```

you'll have to update the definition of `isNumberKey` to accept the parameters provided and use the control's method of canceling the action.

ClientSideEvents reference:
http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/ASPNET/2009.1/CLR3.5/html/Infragistics35.WebUI.WebDataInput.v9.1~Infragistics.WebUI.WebDataInput.WebTextEdit~ClientSideEvents.html